# Add a legend to a combined Plot

Tags: plotting, legending, map

I have trouble adding a second legend to this map (see picture underneath). I need the legend to that show each existing bubble size, with the respective rainbow color (from the map) and with the respective number (from 3 (purple) to 7 (red)) and the legend title "Happiness scores"?

As it is a combination of two maps, it appears to be rather complicated. I would be happy for any help!

Here are the codes, "DataACT1" being the country names and "DataACT2" the respective happiness scores (both provided in the dataset):

```
DataACT1Combination = Transpose[{DataACT1, DataACT2}];
DataACT1Combination$TMP = DeleteCases[DeleteCases[Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} &, DataACT1Combination], {"", ""}], {_, "-"}];

data = Map[Rule[Entity["Country", #[[1]]], #[[2]]] &, DataACT1Combination$TMP];

  H = GeoBubbleChart[data, BubbleSizes -> {0.02, 0.04}, 
  BubbleScale -> "Diameter", ImageSize -> 1000, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", GeoRange -> "World", 
  GeoBackground -> None]
DevelopedCountries = {Entity\["Country", "Albania"\], Entity\["Country", "Algeria"\], Entity\["Country", "Argentina"\], Entity\["Country", "Australia"\], Entity\["Country", "Austria"\], Entity\["Country", "Azerbaijan"\], Entity\["Country", "Bahamas"\], Entity\["Country", "Bahrain"\], Entity\["Country", "Barbados"\], Entity\["Country", "Belarus"\], Entity\["Country", "Belgium"\], Entity\["Country", "BosniaHerzegovina"\],Entity\["Country", "Botswana"\], Entity\["Country", "Brazil"\], Entity\["Country", "Brunei"\], Entity\["Country", "Bulgaria"\], Entity\["Country", "Canada"\], Entity\["Country", "Chile"\], Entity\["Country", "China"\], Entity\["Country", "Colombia"\], Entity\["Country", "CostaRica"\], Entity\["Country", "Croatia"\], Entity\["Country", "Cuba"\], Entity\["Country", "Cyprus"\], Entity\["Country", "CzechRepublic"\], Entity\["Country", "Denmark"\], Entity\["Country", "Dominica"\], Entity\["Country", "DominicanRepublic"\],Entity\["Country", "Ecuador"\], Entity\["Country", "Egypt"\],Entity\["Country", "EquatorialGuinea"\], Entity\["Country", "Estonia"\],Entity\["Country", "Finland"\], Entity\["Country", "France"\], Entity\["Country", "Gabon"\], Entity\["Country", "Georgia"\], Entity\["Country", "Germany"\], Entity\["Country", "Greece"\], Entity\["Country", "Hungary"\], Entity\["Country", "Iceland"\], Entity\["Country", "Indonesia"\], Entity\["Country", "Iran"\], Entity\["Country", "Iraq"\], Entity\["Country", "Ireland"\], Entity\["Country", "Israel"\], Entity\["Country", "Italy"\], Entity\["Country", "Japan"\], Entity\["Country", "Jordan"\], Entity\["Country", "Kazakhstan"\], Entity\["Country", "SouthKorea"\], Entity\["Country", "Kuwait"\], Entity\["Country", "Latvia"\], Entity\["Country", "Lebanon"\], Entity\["Country", "Liechtenstein"\], Entity\["Country", "Lithuania"\], Entity\["Country", "Luxembourg"\], Entity\["Country", "Macedonia"\], Entity\["Country", "Malaysia"\], Entity\["Country", "Maldives"\], Entity\["Country", "Malta"\], Entity\["Country", "Mauritius"\], Entity\["Country", "Mexico"\], Entity\["Country", "Mongolia"\], Entity\["Country", "Montenegro"\], Entity\["Country", "Namibia"\], Entity\["Country", "Netherlands"\], Entity\["Country", "NewZealand"\], Entity\["Country", "Norway"\], Entity\["Country", "Oman"\], Entity\["Country", "Panama"\], Entity\["Country", "Peru"\], Entity\["Country", "Poland"\], Entity\["Country", "Portugal"\], Entity\["Country", "Qatar"\], Entity\["Country", "Romania"\], Entity\["Country", "Russia"\], Entity\["Country", "SaintLucia"\], Entity\["Country", "SaintVincentGrenadines"\], Entity\["Country", "SaudiArabia"\], Entity\["Country", "Serbia"\], Entity\["Country", "Seychelles"\], Entity\["Country", "Singapore"\], Entity\["Country", "Slovakia"\], Entity\["Country", "Slovenia"\], Entity\["Country", "SouthAfrica"\], Entity\["Country", "SouthSudan"\], Entity\["Country", "Spain"\], Entity\["Country", "Sudan"\], Entity\["Country", "Suriname"\], Entity\["Country", "Sweden"\], Entity\["Country", "Syria"\], Entity\["Country", "Tanzania"\], Entity\["Country", "TrinidadTobago"\], Entity\["Country", "Tunisia"\], Entity\["Country", "Turkey"\], Entity\["Country", "Turkmenistan"\], Entity\["Country", "UnitedArabEmirates"\], Entity\["Country", "UnitedKingdom"\], Entity\["Country", "UnitedStates"\], Entity\["Country", "Uruguay"\], Entity\["Country", "Venezuela"\]}
DevelopingCountries = {Entity\["Country", "Afghanistan"\], Entity\["Country", "Angola"\], Entity\["Country", "Armenia"\], Entity\["Country", "Benin"\], Entity\["Country", "Bhutan"\], Entity\["Country", "Bolivia"\], Entity\["Country", "BurkinaFaso"\], Entity\["Country", "Burundi"\], Entity\["Country", "CapeVerde"\], Entity\["Country", "Cambodia"\], Entity\["Country", "Cameroon"\], Entity\["Country", "CentralAfricanRepublic"\], Entity\["Country", "Chad"\], Entity\["Country", "Comoros"\], Entity\["Country", "DemocraticRepublicCongo"\], Entity\["Country", "RepublicCongo"\], Entity\["Country", "IvoryCoast"\],Entity\["Country", "Djibouti"\], Entity\["Country", "ElSalvador"\], Entity\["Country", "Eritrea"\], Entity\["Country", "Swaziland"\], Entity\["Country", "Ethiopia"\], Entity\["Country", "Fiji"\], Entity\["Country", "Gambia"\], Entity\["Country", "Ghana"\], Entity\["Country", "Guatemala"\], Entity\["Country", "Guinea"\], Entity\["Country", "GuineaBissau"\], Entity\["Country", "Guyana"\], Entity\["Country", "Haiti"\], Entity\["Country", "Honduras"\], Entity\["Country", "India"\], Entity\["Country", "Jamaica"\], Entity\["Country", "Kenya"\], Entity\["Country", "Kiribati"\], Entity\["Country", "Kosovo"\], Entity\["Country", "Kyrgyzstan"\], Entity\["Country", "Laos"\], Entity\["Country", "Lesotho"\], Entity\["Country", "Liberia"\], Entity\["Country", "Libya"\], Entity\["Country", "Madagascar"\], Entity\["Country", "Malawi"\], Entity\["Country", "Mali"\], Entity\["Country", "Mauritania"\], Entity\["Country", "Micronesia"\], Entity\["Country", "Moldova"\], Entity\["Country", "Morocco"\], Entity\["Country", "Mozambique"\], Entity\["Country", "Myanmar"\], Entity\["Country", "Nepal"\], Entity\["Country", "Nicaragua"\], Entity\["Country", "Niger"\], Entity\["Country", "Nigeria"\], Entity\["Country", "Pakistan"\], Entity\["Country", "PapuaNewGuinea"\], Entity\["Country", "Paraguay"\], Entity\["Country", "Philippines"\], Entity\["Country", "Rwanda"\], Entity\["Country", "Samoa"\], Entity\["Country", "SaoTomePrincipe"\], Entity\["Country", "Senegal"\], Entity\["Country", "SierraLeone"\], Entity\["Country", "SolomonIslands"\], Entity\["Country", "SriLanka"\], Entity\["Country", "Taiwan"\], Entity\["Country", "Tajikistan"\], Entity\["Country", "EastTimor"\], Entity\["Country", "Togo"\], Entity\["Country", "Tonga"\], Entity\["Country", "Uganda"\], Entity\["Country", "Ukraine"\], Entity\["Country", "Uzbekistan"\], Entity\["Country", "Vanuatu"\], Entity\["Country", "Vietnam"\], Entity\["Country", "Yemen"\], Entity\["Country", "Zambia"\], Entity\["Country", "Zimbabwe"\]}]

FinalPlotCountries =
 Labeled[
  GeoRegionValuePlot[Join[
     Map[Rule[#, Opacity[.2, Red]] &, DevelopedCountries],
     Map[Rule[#, Opacity[.2, Blue]] &, DevelopingCountries]
     ], GeoLabels -> False, LabelStyle -> {8, Bold, Italic}, 
    ImageSize -> 1000, GeoRange -> "World", 
    Epilog -> {H[[1, 1]], 
      Inset[SwatchLegend[{Opacity[.2, Red], 
         Opacity[.2, Blue]}, {"developed countries    ", 
         "developing countries    "}, LegendLayout -> "Row"], 
       Scaled[{0.5, 0.03}]]}] // Framed, 
  Style["Development status of countries and their happiness score", 
   25, FontFamily -> "Times"], Top]
```

[image: Map in which I need to add another legend]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the option `ChartLegends` in `GeoBubbleChart` and `PlotLegends` in `GeoRegionValuePlot` and combine the two plots with `Show` the legends are automatically combined:

```
SeedRandom[7777]
thirtycountries = RandomEntity["Country", 30];

population = DeleteMissing[# -> #[ "Population"] & /@ thirtycountries];
minmax1 = QuantityMagnitude@MinMax[population[[All, 2]]];

hscore = # -> RandomReal[100] & /@ thirtycountries;
minmax2 = QuantityMagnitude@MinMax[hscore[[All, 2]]];

gbc = GeoBubbleChart[population, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   BubbleSizes -> {.02, .05}, GeoRange -> "World", 
   GeoBackground -> None, 
   ChartLegends -> Placed[SwatchLegend[ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax1}] /@ 
       QuantityMagnitude[Values[population]], 
      CommonName@Keys[population], LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, 
      LegendLabel -> Style["population", 16], 
      LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"], Right]];

grvp = GeoRegionValuePlot[hscore, GeoLabels -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], ImageSize -> 800, GeoRange -> "World", 
   Frame -> True, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   FrameTicks -> None, 
   PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendLabel -> Style["hscore", 16], 
      LegendLayout -> "Row"], Above]];

Show[grvp, gbc]
```

[image]

Alternatively, create legends outside `GeoBubbleChart` and `GeoRegionValuePlot` and add them to `Show[grvp, gbc]` using [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html):

```
legend1 = SwatchLegend[ColorData[{"Rainbow", minmax1}] /@ 
    QuantityMagnitude[Values[population]], CommonName@Keys[population], 
   LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, 
   LegendLabel -> Style["population", 16], LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"];

legend2 = BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", minmax2}, 
   LegendLabel -> Style["hscore", 16], LegendLayout -> "Row"];

gbc = GeoBubbleChart[population, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   BubbleSizes -> {.02, .05}, GeoRange -> "World", GeoBackground -> None];

grvp = GeoRegionValuePlot[hscore, GeoLabels -> False, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], ImageSize -> 800, GeoRange -> "World", 
   Frame -> True, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   PlotLegends -> None, FrameTicks -> None];

Legended[Show[grvp, gbc], Thread[Placed[{legend1, legend2}, {After, Above}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! Exactly what I needed, the second option worked great.